# Finding $c_{-3}$ in the laurent series of a function.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{z^2-1}}$ I want to compute the $c_{-3}$ coefficient in the laurent series of $f(z)$ around $z=1$. Here
$c_{-3}=Res((z-1)^2f(z),z=1)$. With a change of variables $w=z-1$ we have  $f(w)=e^{\frac{1}{w(w+2)}}$
we obtain $c_{-3}=Res(w^2f(w),w=0)$. Now
$$\frac{1}{w(w+2)}=\frac{1}{2w}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}w-\frac{1}{16}w^2+\cdots$$
We need only this part $$u=\frac{1}{2w}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}w$$ that will intervene in the computation of $c_{-3}$. Now $$e^u=1+u+u^2/2!+u^3/3!+\cdots$$
We compute
$$u^5=\frac{1}{32w^5}+\cdots$$
$$u^6=\frac{1}{64w^6}-\frac{3}{64w^5}+\cdots$$

$$u^7=\frac{1}{128w^7}-\frac{7}{256w^6} + \frac{7}{128w^5}+\cdots$$

After multiplying by $w^2$ we see that the sum of the coefficients of $\frac{1}{w^3}$ would give
$$c_{-3}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2^n-1)}{2^{n+4}(n+4)!}$$
Using a software I find $$c_{-3}=-\frac{(3 - 48 \sqrt e + 28 e)}{(48 e)}=0.0002$$
Is my work correct and is there any easier way to find $c_{-3}$.

Comment: Is it $\;\frac1{z^2}-1\;$ or $\;\frac1{z^2-1}\;$ in the exponent...??

Comment: it is $\frac{1}{z^2-1}$

Comment: Observe that $f(z)=e^{-{1\over 2(z+1)}}e^{{1\over 2(z-1)}}.$ This should simplify the calculations substantially.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$f(z)=e^{-{1\over 2(z+1)}}e^{{1\over 2(z-1)}}$$
Let $u={1\over z-1}.$ Then
$$f(z)=g(u):=e^{-{u\over 2(1+2u)}}e^{{1\over 2}u} =e^{u^2\over 1+2u}$$
The function $g(u)$ is holomorphic for $|u|<{1\over 2}.$
We get $$c_{-3}={g^{'''}(0)\over 6}$$
Furthermore
$$g(u)=e^{u^2\over 1+2u}=1+{u^2\over 1+2u}+O(u^4)=1+u^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2u)^n+O(u^4)$$ Thus
$${g'''(0)\over 6}= -2$$

Comment: why $c_{-3}=\frac{g'''(0)}{6}$ ? it's $c_{-3}$ not $c_3$. If I understood you well, It"s the coefficient of $\frac{1}{u^3}$ in the laurent series of $u^2g(u)$ around $u=0$.

Comment: When you substitute $u=(z-1)^{-1}$ then $u^3=(z-1)^{-3}.$ Hence we look for the coefficient of $u^3$ in the expansion of $g(u).$